# HTML form post call hidden field

Tags: javascript, html, post

I am trying to do a post call for the login page. User manually enters username/password. However, I want the below field to be set name=username when user inputs his/her username.

I have these fields below. And I have a hidden field and would like to replace the username bit with the username that user manually enters.

```
<input class="form-control" type="hidden" required name="username" placeholder="Username">
<input class="form-control" type="password" required name="password" placeholder="Password">

<input class="form-control" type="hidden" required name="arg" placeholder="name">
```

So it has to be

```
username=stack
password=userset
arg='name=stack'
```

Comment: The question is not clear, do you want to change input `arg`'s placeholder or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using jQuery. Here I have an example where the user still hasn't submited the form.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input[name='username']").keyup(function() {
         $("input[name='arg']").val("'name=" + $(this).val() + "'");
    });

});
```

If you really want to get $_POST values, you have to serialize them using some php.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $post = <?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>;
</script>
```

Then you can access your variable using $post["username"]. But i don't see why you would use this solution, since you can just use regular php to do this.

In your code this should look like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form#form1').submit(function(){
            $.ajax({type: "Post",
                    url: $('form').attr('action'),
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                        alert("Login successful. Please press OK to be redirected. Redirecting in 5 seconds.");
                        window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = "/login"},5000);},
                        error: function(data, status, xhr) {
                            $('form').trigger("reset");
                            alert("Failed to login. Please try again.");
                        }
                    });

                return false;
                alert("AJAX request successfully completed");
            });



          $("input[name='username']").keyup(function() {
              $("input[name='arg']").val("'name=" + $(this).val() + "'");
          });
     });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly what you want to do, it sounds like you want to get the `input` DOM object and change its placeholder attribute every time the user changes the value in the username text input box.

You can grab the DOM elements using `getElementsByName('NAME')[0]` (assuming the names are unique, or even better use IDs instead to make sure they are unique).

Then attach a function to listen for changes and swap in `placeholder`'s new value using `inputDomObject.addEventListener("change", functionToHandleChanges);`

You can set the `placeholder` value on the input's DOM object (and therefore on the page) using `placeholderDomObject.setAttribute("placeholder", "thingToSetItTo");`

If you need any clarification just leave a comment :)

Comment: So I have the username field and arg field. Username field is visible and arg is hidden. If a person enters in stack as username. I want the hidden field to be entered as name=stack as hidden. Is this possible?

Comment: Yeah, like I described above in JavaScript, just prepend`"name=" to the value you grab in the onchange event handler function. You can use the `.value` field of the username input's DOM object to get the value they entered. (I'm not sure of your level of JavaScript, is this description okay?)

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understand you correctly. Can you write out it in a code? I am not experienced at js.

Comment: Is this something that I can do it within html? Or do I need to use javascript? I am not trying to grab it. This is part of the post call.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this in just HTML, you'd have to learn some basic JS, or alternatively construct the value you want on the server (if it's website you're posting to).